Macro only works when run from "view macros" menu in excel, not with keyboard shortcut
My macro keyboard shortcut does not run the macro properly. But selecting the macro manually does.
From an already opened workbook, I am trying to open another workbook (Template.xlsx) and copy a sheet from the first workbook into this newly opened workbook. It works when I open the "view macros" menu in excel and click "run". But when I use the keyboard shortcut, it only opens the second workbook and does not copy my sheet into it. Any idea why this is and how to get my keyboard shortcut to work?

Sub MergeTest3()
'
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
'

Dim CompWrksht As Workbook
Set CompWrksht = ActiveWorkbook


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim template As String
template = "V:\Nick\Validation Worksheets\ECC\Maui Wild Fires\Template.xlsx"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(template)

CompWrksht.Activate

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Move Before:=Workbooks("Template.xlsx").Sheets(1)
    
    'CompWrksht.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    'CompWrksht.Sheets("Sheet1").Move Before:=Workbooks("Template.xlsx").Sheets(1)
    
End Sub



Have you tried qualifying your sheet references with the workbook it's from instead of relying on what is active at the time? Activate and Select should not be used and there is no reason to use them in this case.

@braX , I need the macro to work for many workbooks. I'm not sure how to write it if the name of the workbook containing the sheet I want to copy will be different every time I need to use this macro.

I would add something like Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Name to make sure you have the right one in your debugging tests. And it looks like you are close in your commented out lines, but you still do not need Activate and Select. - Also, you can use Before:=wb.Sheets(1) since you saved the workbook into a variable.

If your shortcut key combination involves the shift key, choose one that doesn't.

@Rory removing shift key worked, thank you

Create Keyboard Shortcut
Improve Code

Use constants and variables to make the code more readable and maintainable.
Avoid using Select and any flavor of Active when possible.

Sub MergeTest3()
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ' Or:
    'Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    MoveSheet wb

End Sub

Sub MoveSheet(swb As Workbook)
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_SHEET_ID As Variant = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_SHEET_ID As Variant = 1
    Const DST_FILE_PATH As String = _
        "V:\Nick\Validation Worksheets\ECC\Maui Wild Fires\Template.xlsx"

    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_ID)
    
    ' Destination (Template)
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(DST_FILE_PATH)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(1)
    
    ' Move source sheet before destination sheet.
    sws.Move Before:=dws
    
End Sub


Note that the constants could easily become parameters of the MoveSheet method.
In the continuation, you can reference the newly added sheet with dwb.Sheets(1) or dws.Previous.

Create Shortcut

Use the Application.OnKey method to create a shortcut of your choice.

Sub CreateKeyboardShortcut()
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
    Application.OnKey "^+Q", "MergeTest3"
End Sub

Sub RemoveKeyboardShortcut()
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
    Application.OnKey "^+Q"
End Sub


Once you've saved the workbook, the shortcut remains with it.

